# How to pass multiple column in partitionby method in Spark

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, hive-metastore

I am a newbie in Spark.I want to write the dataframe data into hive table. Hive table is partitioned on mutliple column. Through, Hivemetastore client I am getting the partition column and passing that as a variable in partitionby clause in write method of dataframe.

```
var1="country","state" (Getting the partiton column names of hive table)
dataframe1.write.partitionBy(s"$var1").mode("overwrite").save(s"$hive_warehouse/$dbname.db/$temp_table/")
```

When I am executing the above code,it is giving me error partiton "country","state" does not exists.
I think it is taking "country","state" as a string.

Can you please help me out.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The partitionBy function takes a `varargs` not a list. You can use this as

```
dataframe1.write.partitionBy("country","state").mode("overwrite").save(s"$hive_warehouse/$dbname.db/$temp_table/")
```

Or in scala you can convert a list into a varargs like

```
val columns = Seq("country","state")
dataframe1.write.partitionBy(columns:_*).mode("overwrite").save(s"$hive_warehouse/$dbname.db/$temp_table/")
```

Comment: Does this work for bucketby in scala? I tried an didnt work